# Cleaning tweets in Python

Tags: python

An example of the JSON file:
https://nofile.io/f/J3EqSk2CWsB/raw_tweets.json

I am trying to extract only the bit with full_text so the output should look something like this:

```
    #Deathstroke 31 @DCComics \u2022 super airDrop opening &amp; it only gets better from there \u2022 it\u2019s not just 
#BatmanMammaMia, folks! #SladeWilson in dept to #Mento &amp; #BruceWayne methodology a bit more cosmopolitan https:\/\/t.co\/jWUGBn4Fqm
```

I am using this code:

```
saveFile = open('raw_tweets.json','r')
for line in saveFile:
    tweet = line.split(':{"full_text":"')[1].split(',"display_text_range":"')[0]
    print(tweet)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\shortening_tweets.py", line 7, in <module>
    tweet = line.split(':{"full_text":"')[1].split(',"display_text_range":"')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Line 7 is the line with the split
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't do `split()` and other low-level stuff with JSON data. Use JSON access tools.

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

tweet = json.loads(line)['extended_tweet']['full_text']
```

Comment: @AIexHall am getting this error:

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)`

Comment: @bybu then you do not have exactly one JSON object per line. I notice that the sample file you gave us has line breaks in random places and a comma at the very beginning. Can you fix the source of the data?